# returning a value using zend forward

Tags: zend-framework

i have a function in another controller which i want to access using the zend forward function,

```
public function creanAction(){

$myvbale=22;

return $myvbale *2;

}
```

in my other controller i have this:

```
public function localForwardAction
{
   this->view->message=$this->_forward("crean","account");
}
```

example from a site is this:

but

i want the message var to contain the return value or outcome from the controller/action specified in the forward function...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_forward()` doesn't return any value, so you cannot do it like this. Maybe you could consider using Zend_Registry for storing `$myvbale`.